# Iteratively adding keys and values to a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the best way to add keys and values in a dictionary. A little context on my problem. I am trying to do graph traversal where each node is a subpage of a basic HTML website. I am looking for the links that each page contains and where they go. I am struggling trying to figure out how to do this iteratively.

Example of what I am talking about:
`Graph = {Current_Page : {links that are on this page}`
`Graph = {page1: {'page2', 'page3' page4'}`

Next I want to go to page 2 and find all the link it has access to and add those to the graph dictionary.
`Graph = {page2: {'page1', 'page3' page4', 'page5'}`

I am fairly new to python, but I will try my best to understand.

Comment: It seems like this would be a valid case to use recursion for, but you would need to make sure you have proper control over recursion depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do is to have all the pages you want to get links for in a list (I assumed `pages`) and have a function for getting links from that page as `get_links()`. You can then use following snippet as a readable and reliable approach to achieve what you are trying to achieve:

```
Graph = {}
for page, page_number in enumerate(pages):
    Graph['page' + page_number] = get_links(page)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This definitely helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can try simply looping through each page, finding the links and then adding them to the dictionary.

```
Graph = {}
for pageNumber in range(0, pagesNumber, 1):
    linkList =  ##I think you figured this part out?
    Graph['page' + pageNumber] = linkList
```

That should add it to the dictionary. Just add in the code to find the links and fill in all the variables, good luck!

Comment: @Braydon, Great to hear! If it's not too much trouble, could you upvote my answer then? Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time I cannot. I have less than 15 reputation and it prevents me from upvoting just yet.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may look at this for a solution this is what I did. I compiled a list of all the webpages that I wanted to get the links on that page to, it is stored in a list called `pages`. I also used a `getLinks`method that would fetch the links for me.

```
graph = {}
for value in pages:
    graph[value] = getLinks(value)
```

This returned a dictionary with the formatting in the original problem statement.